# Follow symbolic links in alternative org-roam directory

Tags: org-mode, directory-local-variables, org-roam, symbolic-links

I use org-roam to take notes. I have two org-roam directories. The alternative one has a `.dir-locals.el` file where I set the value of `org-roam-directory` and `org-roam-db-location` with the path to the alternative directory and its database, respectively.

I have set the org-mode `find-file-visit-truename` variable to `t`, so org-mode is able to follow symlinks. This works fine with the main org-roam directory, being able to follow symlinks and indexing the notes pointed by it. But this is not the case for the alternative directory. I suppose there is a variable that I need to add to my `.dir-locals.el` file to enable this, but I have found nothing in the documentation about it.